# Something's wrong with my gems

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Everytime I run `gem install something` , I get

```
Successfully installed bundle-0.0.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `source_paths' for #<Gem::Specification:0x6ab2aec bundle-0.0.1>
```

I tried to reinstall gem, tried to reinstall bundle/bundler - no help. When I try `rails new blog`, I get

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Could not find gem 'sqlite3' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Use rvm. `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Comment: @anothermh could you please tell me more verbose what should I do next with this installation process etc

Comment: I recommend reading [Installing RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install). You should use RVM to install Ruby, then after you have installed RVM and Ruby retry your `gem install` and `rails new` operations.

Comment: @anothermh I get `* To start using RVM you need to run ` `source /home/ivan/.rvm/scripts/rvm` `
    `in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.`
`




but then
`source /home/ivan/.rvm/scripts/rvm
WARNING:
      Could not source '/home/ivan/.rvm/scripts/scripts/base' as file does not exist.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.`

Comment: Do you have this at the top of your `Gemfile`: `source 'https://rubygems.org'`

Comment: @NickM where is Gemfile located?

Comment: It's at the root of your app in all versions of Rails